# How to remove/delete a string that has been just entered by a user and read by console from Console Interface Screen?

Tags: c#, command-line, console, command-line-interface, console-application

I want to delete a user input if a condition is not met, and keep the Console interface same and intact without using `Console.Clear()` or `goto menu;`

[image]

I want to delete whatever was entered by the user if a condition is not met.
How can I do that?

If I use `Console.Clear()` or `goto menu;` the same code repeats over and over again and it makes the app slow and exhausting to code.

```
    using System;

namespace KONSOLAdamaAsmacaODEV111822
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
        menuilk:
            int val;
            string[] secilenHarfler = new string[29];
            string cevap;
            string cevap2;
            int sayac = 0;
            int sayac2 = 0;
            int sayac3 = 0;
            int sayacCevap1 = 0;
            int sayacCevap2 = 0;
            int puan = 0;
            string[] alttire = { "_ ", "_ ", "_ ", "_ ", "_ ", "_ " };
            string[] harfler = { "A ", "B ", "C ", "Ç ", "D ", "E ", "F ", "G ", "G ", "H ", "I ", "İ ", "J ", "K ", "L ", "M ", "N ", "O ", "Ö ", "P ", "Q ", "R ", "S ", "Ş ", "T ", "U ", "Ü ", "V ", "W ", "X ", "Y ", "Z " };
            string[] isim = { "S ", "E ", "R ", "D ", "A ", "R" };
        menu:
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("                ********** Adam Asmaca Oyunu **********");
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine(" ASMA SÜRECİ : ");
            Console.WriteLine();
            if (sayac == 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
            else if (sayac == 1)
            {
                Console.Clear();
                Console.WriteLine("                ********** Adam Asmaca Oyunu **********");
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.WriteLine(" ASMA SÜRECİ : ");
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.WriteLine(" -----");
            }
            else if (sayac == 2)
            {
                Console.Clear();
                Console.WriteLine("                ********** Adam Asmaca Oyunu **********");
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.WriteLine(" ASMA SÜRECİ : ");
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.WriteLine("   |");
                Console.WriteLine("   |");
                Console.WriteLine("   |");
                Console.WriteLine("   |");
                Console.WriteLine("   |");
                Console.WriteLine("   |");
                Console.WriteLine(" -----");
            }
            else if (sayac == 3)
            {
                Console.Clear();
                Console.WriteLine("                ********** Adam Asmaca Oyunu **********");
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.WriteLine(" ASMA SÜRECİ : ");
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.WriteLine("   __________");
                Console.WriteLine("   |");
                Console.WriteLine("   |");
                Console.WriteLine("   |");
                Console.WriteLine("   |");
                Console.WriteLine("   |");
                Console.WriteLine("   |");
                Console.WriteLine(" -----");
            }
            else if (sayac == 4)
            {
                Console.Clear();
                Console.WriteLine("                ********** Adam Asmaca Oyunu **********");
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.WriteLine(" ASMA SÜRECİ : ");
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.WriteLine("   __________");
                Console.WriteLine("   |         |");
                Console.WriteLine("   |         |");
                Console.WriteLine("   |");
                Console.WriteLine("   |");
                Console.WriteLine("   |");
                Console.WriteLine("   |");
                Console.WriteLine(" -----");
            }
            else if (sayac == 5)
            {
                Console.Clear();
                Console.WriteLine("                ********** Adam Asmaca Oyunu **********");
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.WriteLine(" ASMA SÜRECİ : ");
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.WriteLine("   __________");
                Console.WriteLine("   |         |");
                Console.WriteLine("   |         |");
                Console.WriteLine("   |         Ō");
                Console.WriteLine("   |");
                Console.WriteLine("   |");
                Console.WriteLine("   |");
                Console.WriteLine(" -----");
            }
            else if (sayac == 6)
            {
                Console.Clear();
                Console.WriteLine("                ********** Adam Asmaca Oyunu **********");
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.WriteLine(" ASMA SÜRECİ : ");
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.WriteLine("   __________");
                Console.WriteLine("   |         |");
                Console.WriteLine("   |         |");
                Console.WriteLine("   |         Ō");
                Console.WriteLine("   |         |");
                Console.WriteLine("   |");
                Console.WriteLine("   |");
                Console.WriteLine(" -----");
            }
            else if (sayac == 7)
            {
                Console.Clear();
                Console.WriteLine("                ********** Adam Asmaca Oyunu **********");
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.WriteLine(" ASMA SÜRECİ : ");
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.WriteLine("   __________");
                Console.WriteLine("   |         |");
                Console.WriteLine("   |         |");
                Console.WriteLine("   |         Ō");
                Console.WriteLine("   |        /|\\");
                Console.WriteLine("   |");
                Console.WriteLine("   |");
                Console.WriteLine(" -----");
            }
            else if (sayac == 8)
            {
                Console.Clear();
                Console.WriteLine("                ********** Adam Asmaca Oyunu **********");
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.WriteLine(" ASMA SÜRECİ : ");
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.WriteLine("   __________");
                Console.WriteLine("   |         |");
                Console.WriteLine("   |         |");
                Console.WriteLine("   |         Ō");
                Console.WriteLine("   |        /|\\");
                Console.WriteLine("   |        / \\");
                Console.WriteLine("   |");
                Console.WriteLine(" -----");
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.WriteLine(" !!!!!!!!  OYUN BİTTİ  !!!!!!!! KAYBETTİNİZ!");
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.WriteLine(" PUAN : " + puan + "   DENEME : " + sayac3);
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.WriteLine(" !!!!!!!! YENİDEN OYNAMAK İSTER MİSİNİZ? E/H");
                cevap2 = Console.ReadLine();
                if (cevap2 == "e" || cevap2 == "E")
                {
                    Console.Clear();
                    goto menuilk;
                }
                else
                {
                    Environment.Exit(0);
                }

            }

            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.Write(" SAKLI KELİME : ");
            for (int i = 0; i < alttire.Length; i++)
            {
                Console.Write(" " + alttire[i]);
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.Write(" HARFLER : ");
            for (int i = 0; i < harfler.Length; i++)
            {
                Console.Write(harfler[i]);
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine(" PUAN : " + puan + "   DENEME : " + sayac3);
            Console.WriteLine();
        aramenu:
            Console.Write(" Harf Gir : ");
            cevap = Console.ReadLine();
            if(!int.TryParse(cevap, out val) && cevap.Length==1)
            {
                switch (cevap)
                {
                    case "a":
                        if (sayacCevap1 < 1)
                        {
                            cevap = "A";
                            sayacCevap1++;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            goto aramenu;
                        }
                        break;
                    case "b":
                        if (sayacCevap2 < 1)
                        {
                            cevap = "B";
                            sayacCevap2++;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            goto aramenu;
                        }
                        break;
                    case "c":
                        cevap = "C";
                        break;
                    case "ç":
                        cevap = "Ç";
                        break;
                    case "d":
                        cevap = "D";
                        break;
                    case "e":
                        cevap = "E";
                        break;
                    case "f":
                        cevap = "F";
                        break;
                    case "g":
                        cevap = "G";
                        break;
                    case "ğ":
                        cevap = "Ğ";
                        break;
                    case "h":
                        cevap = "H";
                        break;
                    case "ı":
                        cevap = "I";
                        break;
                    case "i":
                        cevap = "İ";
                        break;
                    case "j":
                        cevap = "J";
                        break;
                    case "k":
                        cevap = "K";
                        break;
                    case "l":
                        cevap = "L";
                        break;
                    case "m":
                        cevap = "M";
                        break;
                    case "n":
                        cevap = "N";
                        break;
                    case "o":
                        cevap = "O";
                        break;
                    case "ö":
                        cevap = "Ö";
                        break;
                    case "p":
                        cevap = "P";
                        break;
                    case "q":
                        cevap = "Q";
                        break;
                    case "r":
                        cevap = "R";
                        break;
                    case "s":
                        cevap = "S";
                        break;
                    case "ş":
                        cevap = "Ş";
                        break;
                    case "t":
                        cevap = "T";
                        break;
                    case "u":
                        cevap = "U";
                        break;
                    case "ü":
                        cevap = "Ü";
                        break;
                    case "v":
                        cevap = "V";
                        break;
                    case "w":
                        cevap = "W";
                        break;
                    case "x":
                        cevap = "X";
                        break;
                    case "y":
                        cevap = "Y";
                        break;
                    case "z":
                        cevap = "Z";
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
                switch (cevap)
                {
                    case "A":
                        sayac3++;
                        Console.Clear();
                        Console.WriteLine("                 ********** Adam Asmaca Oyunu **********");
                        Console.WriteLine();

                        for (int i = 0; i < harfler.Length; i++)
                        {
                            if (harfler[i] == "A ")
                            {
                                harfler[i] = "- ";
                                for (int j = 0; j < alttire.Length; j++)
                                {
                                    if (j == 4)//SERDAR'IN 5. harfi
                                    {
                                        alttire[j] = "A ";
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        Console.Write(" HARFLER : ");
                        for (int i = 0; i < harfler.Length; i++)
                        {
                            Console.Write(harfler[i]);
                        }
                        Console.WriteLine();
                        Console.WriteLine();
                        if ("A " == isim[0] || "A " == isim[1] || "A " == isim[2] || "A " == isim[3] || "A " == isim[4] || "A " == isim[5])
                        {
                            puan += 10;
                            for (int k = 0; k < alttire.Length; k++)
                            {
                                if (isim[k] == alttire[k])
                                {
                                    sayac2++;
                                    if (sayac2 == 11)
                                    {
                                        goto end;
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            puan -= 10;
                            sayac++;
                        }
                        goto menu;
                    case "B":
                        sayac3++;

                        Console.Clear();
                        Console.WriteLine("                 ********** Adam Asmaca Oyunu **********");
                        for (int i = 0; i < harfler.Length; i++)
                        {
                            if (harfler[i] == "B ")
                            {
                                harfler[i] = "- ";
                            }
                        }
                        Console.Write(" HARFLER : ");
                        for (int i = 0; i < harfler.Length; i++)
                        {
                            Console.Write(harfler[i]);
                        }
                        Console.WriteLine();
                        Console.WriteLine();
                        if ("B " == isim[0] || "B " == isim[1] || "B " == isim[2] || "B " == isim[3] || "B " == isim[4] || "B " == isim[5])
                        {
                            puan += 10;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            puan -= 10;
                            sayac++;
                        }
                        goto menu;
                    case "C":
                        sayac3++;

                        Console.Clear();
                        Console.WriteLine("                 ********** Adam Asmaca Oyunu **********");
                        for (int i = 0; i < harfler.Length; i++)
                        {
                            if (harfler[i] == "C ")
                            {
                                harfler[i] = "- ";
                            }
                        }
                        Console.Write(" HARFLER : ");
                        for (int i = 0; i < harfler.Length; i++)
                        {
                            Console.Write(harfler[i]);
                        }
                        Console.WriteLine();
                        Console.WriteLine();
                        if ("C " == isim[0] || "C " == isim[1] || "C " == isim[2] || "C " == isim[3] || "C " == isim[4] || "C " == isim[5])
                        {
                            puan += 10;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            puan -= 10;
                            sayac++;
                        }
                        goto menu;
                    case "Ç":
                        sayac3++;

                        Console.Clear();
                        Console.WriteLine("                 ********** Adam Asmaca Oyunu **********");
                        for (int i = 0; i < harfler.Length; i++)
                        {
                            if (harfler[i] == "Ç ")
                            {
                                harfler[i] = "- ";
                            }
                        }
                        Console.Write(" HARFLER : ");
                        for (int i = 0; i < harfler.Length; i++)
                        {
                            Console.Write(harfler[i]);
                        }
                        Console.WriteLine();
                        Console.WriteLine();
                        if ("Ç " == isim[0] || "Ç " == isim[1] || "Ç " == isim[2] || "Ç " == isim[3] || "Ç " == isim[4] || "Ç " == isim[5])
                        {
                            puan += 10;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            puan -= 10;
                            sayac++;
                        }
                        goto menu;
                    case "D":
                        sayac3++;

                        Console.Clear();
                        Console.WriteLine("                 ********** Adam Asmaca Oyunu **********");
                        Console.WriteLine();

                        for (int i = 0; i < harfler.Length; i++)
                        {
                            if (harfler[i] == "D ")
                            {
                                harfler[i] = "- ";
                                for (int j = 0; j < alttire.Length; j++)
                                {
                                    if (j == 3)//SERDAR'IN 4. harfi
                                    {
                                        alttire[j] = "D ";
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        Console.Write(" HARFLER : ");
                        for (int i = 0; i < harfler.Length; i++)
                        {
                            Console.Write(harfler[i]);
                        }
                        Console.WriteLine();
                        Console.WriteLine();
                        if ("D " == isim[0] || "D " == isim[1] || "D " == isim[2] || "D " == isim[3] || "D " == isim[4] || "D " == isim[5])
                        {
                            puan += 10;
                            for (int k = 0; k < alttire.Length; k++)
                            {
                                if (isim[k] == alttire[k])
                                {
                                    sayac2++;
                                    if (sayac2 == 11)
                                    {
                                        goto end;
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            puan -= 10;
                            sayac++;
                        }
                        goto menu;
                    case "E":
                        sayac3++;

                        Console.Clear();
                        Console.WriteLine("                 ********** Adam Asmaca Oyunu **********");
                        Console.WriteLine();

                        Console.WriteLine();
                        for (int i = 0; i < harfler.Length; i++)
                        {
                            if (harfler[i] == "E ")
                            {
                                harfler[i] = "- ";
                                for (int j = 0; j < alttire.Length; j++)
                                {
                                    if (j == 1)//SERDAR'IN 5. harfi
                                    {
                                        alttire[j] = "E ";
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        Console.Write(" HARFLER : ");
                        for (int i = 0; i < harfler.Length; i++)
                        {
                            Console.Write(harfler[i]);
                        }
                        Console.WriteLine();
                        Console.WriteLine();
                        if ("E " == isim[0] || "E " == isim[1] || "E " == isim[2] || "E " == isim[3] || "E " == isim[4] || "E " == isim[5])
                        {
                            puan += 10;
                            for (int k = 0; k < alttire.Length; k++)
                            {
                                if (isim[k] == alttire[k])
                                {
                                    sayac2++;
                                    if (sayac2 == 11)
                                    {
                                        goto end;
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            puan -= 10;
                            sayac++;
                        }
                        goto menu;
                    case "F":
                        sayac3++;

                        Console.Clear();
                        Console.WriteLine("                 ********** Adam Asmaca Oyunu **********");
                        for (int i = 0; i < harfler.Length; i++)
                        {
                            if (harfler[i] == "F ")
                            {
                                harfler[i] = "- ";
                            }
                        }
                        Console.Write(" HARFLER : ");
                        for (int i = 0; i < harfler.Length; i++)
                        {
                            Console.Write(harfler[i]);
                        }
                        Console.WriteLine();
                        Console.WriteLine();
                        if ("F " == isim[0] || "F " == isim[1] || "F " == isim[2] || "F " == isim[3] || "F " == isim[4] || "F " == isim[5])
                        {
                            puan += 10;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            puan -= 10;
                            sayac++;
                        }
                        goto menu;
                    case "G":
                        sayac3++;

                        Console.Clear();
                        Console.WriteLine("                 ********** Adam Asmaca Oyunu **********");
                        for (int i = 0; i < harfler.Length; i++)
                        {
                            if (harfler[i] == "G ")
                            {
                                harfler[i] = "- ";
                            }
                        }
                        Console.Write(" HARFLER : ");
                        for (int i = 0; i < harfler.Length; i++)
                        {
                            Console.Write(harfler[i]);
                        }
                        Console.WriteLine();
                        Console.WriteLine();
                        if ("G " == isim[0] || "G " == isim[1] || "G " == isim[2] || "G " == isim[3] || "G " == isim[4] || "G " == isim[5])
                        {
                            puan += 10;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            puan -= 10;
                            sayac++;
                        }
                        goto menu;
                    case "Ğ":
                        sayac3++;

                        Console.Clear();
                        Console.WriteLine("                 ********** Adam Asmaca Oyunu **********");
```

Comment: Show your code, otherwise we can't help

Comment: @TimSchmelter here is the code.

Comment: @TimSchmelter the code is 6000 line while stackoverflow only allows for 3000, so you are seeing only the half of it I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
public static void ClearConsoleLine()
{
    var originalLineCursor = Console.CursorTop;

    Console.SetCursorPosition(0, originalLineCursor);
    Console.Write(new string(' ', Console.WindowWidth)); 
    Console.SetCursorPosition(0, originalLineCursor);
}
```

Since I can't see the entirety of the code, you may need to adjust the line by subtracting from `Console.CursorTop`.